# Logic: Using mathematical induction to prove a conditional statement

Tags: logic, induction

Can a statement of the form
$$ \forall a \in \mathbb N, P(a)\implies Q(a)$$ 
be proved by using mathematical induction?

Comment: Yes?  Is there a reason you think it can't?

Comment: I couldn't personally think of a concrete example to that form, meaning I couldn't try to prove it by induction. Therefore, I don't know if it is possible or not. I'd appreciate it, if you could give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any proveable statement of the type $\forall a\in\mathbb N: S(a)$, where $S$ is **any logical expression about $a$**, can be proven by mathematical induction. In your case, $S(a)$ is equal to $P(a)\implies Q(a)$, there's no reason to think $S$ is anything special.

Naturally, induction may not always be the *easiest* way to prove the statement but it will always work.

Comment: A very good and clear explanation. Thank you!